# How to send a image/gif from a folder? (discord.py)

Tags: python, image, import, discord

I am trying to send images/gifs that I scraped from the web to a discord channel, I have been running into a few issues such as:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '__pycache__'`

Not entirely sure what the issue means or how to fix it!

Code:

**Modules**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
# import giphy_client
# from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
from tokens import token
import random
import os

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('test')
async def anime(ctx):

    #test = discord.Embed
    #test.set.title = ("hi"),
    #test.set.image = ('.png'),
    #test.set_footer(
    #    text=f"Powered by xxx")

    files = []
    for file in os.listdir():
            if file.endswith('.jpg'):
                files.append(file)

    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(file))




client.run(token, bot=True)
```

I understand things such as `bot=True` is not needed, that is purely because I am testing things.
I would like to send the images/gifs from the folder as a embed but I'm not entirely sure how to do that, hence why I blocked it out but either way I'm just trying to figure out how to import/send images/gifs to discord without using an api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass in a list for `discord.File` function. You need to pass in the file path.

```py
files = []
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        files.append(file)

for file in files: # taking the path out of "files"
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(file))
```

Comment: This didn't work, there are several format errors.

Comment: what's the error? Can you provide a full traceback?